# Deleting duplicate rows based on logical operation in R

Tags: r, filter, duplicates, rows

I have data like this:

```
ID                SHape Length  
180139746001000           2

180139746001000           1
```

I want to delete the duplicate rows whichever has the less shape length. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to keep the row with the maximum shape length, by ID ?

Answer (score 1):

with

```
df <- data.table(matrix(c(102:106,106:104,1:3,1:3,5:6),nrow = 8))
colnames(df) <- c("ID","Shape Length")
```

just use `duplicated` after sorting

```
setkey(df,"V2")
df[!duplicated(V1, fromLast = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the highest shape length for each ID by performing

```
df %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
arrange(SHape.Length) %>%
slice(1) %>%
ungroup()
```

Comment: I would recommend naming your column names without spaces as it is bad coding standard. you can fix that by doing a simple `stringr::str_replace_all("\\s","_")`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was in a hurry, hence, I wrote my names like that. But in the actual database, they are named without space.